# Merge 'round' and 'rounded' tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I'm thinking we should probably merge the [round](/questions/tagged/round) and [rounded](/questions/tagged/rounded) tags on SO.  They mean the same thing as far as I'm aware, neither has a tag wiki, and they're both being used on the same posts to mean the same thing.  What say you, meta?

Comment: I'd say burn them, they don't work well as standalone tags.

Comment: Not even close. [tag:round] appears to be used much more frequently with rounding numbers. [tag:rounded], while used with rounding numbers, is also frequently used in regards to CSS and other display languages for rounded corners. They are ambiguous so they should be burned.

Comment: @animuson do you think we should retag the ones who are about rounded corners with the already existent [tag:rounded-corners]?

Comment: @animuson I know they're used to mean two different things, but both words can be used to mean each of those things (ie. round *or* rounded could mean rounding numbers, round *or* rounded could refer to CSS). So even though they can mean more than one thing, they still mean the *same* things. When referring to rounding numbers they seem to be pretty useful to me, though. Can you elaborate on why you think they should be burned?

Comment: They should be burned for exactly that reason. They're ambiguous, and we don't keep tags that have a bunch of different meanings. Tags are meant to categorize, and if it has multiple meanings, it doesn't categorize anything.

Comment: @animuson Okay.  Makes sense, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done the following:

- Retagged the 32 questions with [rounded](/questions/tagged/rounded) and [corners](/questions/tagged/corners) to [rounded-corners](/questions/tagged/rounded-corners)
- Retagged the 9 questions with [rounded](/questions/tagged/rounded) and [corner](/questions/tagged/corner) to [rounded-corners](/questions/tagged/rounded-corners)
- As a result of the above, I've merged [corner](/questions/tagged/corner) with [corners](/questions/tagged/corners)
- Retagged 16 questions with [round](/questions/tagged/round) and [corners](/questions/tagged/corners) to [rounded-corners](/questions/tagged/rounded-corners)
- Of the 33 questions left with [rounded](/questions/tagged/rounded), I removed the [rounded](/questions/tagged/rounded) tag, or replaced it with [rounded-corners](/questions/tagged/rounded-corners) or [number-rounding](/questions/tagged/number-rounding) where appropriate.  [rounded](/questions/tagged/rounded) no longer exists.

I'll update this as I make my way through the rest.

Comment: Wow, casper, you're awesome.  Thanks for cleaning this up!  That's a great solution and I appreciate all the effort you put into doing it : D