# Merge the rounding tag into the number-rounding tag

Tags: support, retag-request

As a result of this question:

[Merge 'round' and 'rounded' tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141447/140951)

The [rounded](/questions/tagged/rounded) and [round](/questions/tagged/round) are being removed, and replaced with [rounded-corners](/questions/tagged/rounded-corners) or [number-rounding](/questions/tagged/number-rounding) (note, this one existed before that question) where appropriate.

The [rounding](/questions/tagged/rounding) tag still exists, and has the following tag wiki:

> Rounding a numerical value means replacing it by another value that is
>   approximately equal but has a shorter, simpler, or more explicit
>   representation.

(Note, I've changed the above, as [the previous version didn't explain things clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6967500/2))

That said, I think that we should merge the [rounding](/questions/tagged/rounding) tag into the [number-rounding](/questions/tagged/number-rounding) tag (or preferably, a new tag, [numerical-rounding](/questions/tagged/numerical-rounding) as that name feels more proper).